# upgrading from jQuery Mobile 1.0 to 1.1.0 and buttons dont respond

Tags: jquery-mobile

So i have looked all over and it seems that not many people are having that much of a problem but i think jquery.mobile has changed how they animate a button press action.

In jQuery Mobile 1.0.0 when you press a button the button action is done right away (android 2.x) (the website i am working on is m.schedulicity.com (not trying to advertise, but its 1.0 and it works just fine on mobile)).

But when we upgraded to mobile 1.1.0 the buttons do not respond like they did.  If i hold the button down the action state will eventually set in (like .2 of a second but it does not respond at all if just tap the button (css wise) but the button is still "clicked" just no animation).

If you have any suggestions i would really appreciate.

### NOTE:

I know you cannot self promote and i am not trying to self promote (with the link) but i wanted to give a really example of jquery1.0 working.  The 1.1.0 is not released yet so i cannot give that.  But i upgraded the css structure and the jquery mobile to 1.1.0 andeverything works, just slower.  So the buttons do not display as "pressed" on tap but on a hold down it will.

Thanks

Comment: Did you also upgrade the jQuery version to 1.7.x?

Comment: Could you post some code? or a link? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: This is a 1.1.0 problem.  @PhillPafford if you take an android and go to http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/about/getting-started.html and scroll to the buttons and press it quickly.  Then press and hold for a moment and you will see the delayed reaction... Its a jquery 1.1.0 issue (i found out about 2 hours ago :( )

Comment: Could you link to the issue? https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues

Comment: I did not look at the issue on jquery's mobile issues.  I just know it exists because on numerous devices on even their own website this "bug" persists and was started on 1.1